# How do I add an image icon on top of a panel div using CSS and Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add an icon on top of the bootstrap panel. So far, I achieve what I want.
[image: Done!]

But when I resize my browser, it is not responsive at all. I'm not a CSS or JS expert so can you help me with this?

```css
img
{
  margin-bottom:-5px;
  width: calc(100%, 2);
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: 540px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 120px;">
   <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/sign-png-wooden-sign-no-mask-image-5721-565.png">
   <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <img src="http://www.line-stickers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/line-mascot.png" class="float-right">
   <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
   </div> 
  </div>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What will happen if the browser becomes smaller?

Comment: It just stay in one place.

Comment: @piawurtzbach but what would you like to happen on resize?  Where should the icon go?

Comment: I want the icon to move according to panel's size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding a `margin-left` to `img` you're probably better just adding `float: right`, then using `clear: both` on the `div` underneath. Then if you feel you want the image to be slightly indented you can just add a `margin-right` to it.

```css
img
{
  margin-bottom:-5px;
  width: calc(100%, 2);
  height: 120px;
  float: right;
}

.panel-danger {
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 120px;">
   <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/sign-png-wooden-sign-no-mask-image-5721-565.png">
   <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <img src="http://www.line-stickers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/line-mascot.png" class="float-right">
   <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
    <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
   </div> 
  </div>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This one is better than the first one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @piawurtzback Thanks, please mark it as the answer if you think it is! :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```css
img {
  margin-bottom: -5px;
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 85px;
  min-width: 60px;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top: 120px;">
    <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/sign-png-wooden-sign-no-mask-image-5721-565.png">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <img src="http://www.line-stickers.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/line-mascot.png" class="float-right">
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">Panel Heading</div>
      <div class="panel-body">Panel Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS code:

```
img
{
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
}
```